# c# parse nested JSON that doesn't use JSON arrays

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a nested json string, instead of using arrays the next level is another json structure. This creates a mess of deserializing using traditional methods.

Most other answers dealing with parsing json have clearly defined structures, and in most cases can be solved using online tools such as http://json2csharp.com/. But because this JSON doesn't use arrays properly I'm having trouble coming up with a solution to deserialize it.

For example:

```
 {
   "time":1516824466,
   "global":{
      "workers":1,
      "hashrate":0
   },
   "algos":{
      "scrypt-n":{
         "workers":1,
         "hashrate":79752.92436043094,
         "hashrateString":"79.75 KH"
      }
   },
   "pools":{
      "garlicoin":{
         "name":"garlicoin",
         "symbol":"GRLC",
         "algorithm":"scrypt-n",
         "poolStats":{
            "validShares":"22855",
            "validBlocks":"3",
            "invalidShares":"59",
            "invalidRate":"0.0026",
            "totalPaid":"296.42722209999999999"
         },
         "blocks":{
            "pending":0,
            "confirmed":2,
            "orphaned":1
         },
         "workers":{
            "Gf3ZXqhWKkm8qLhSHvyrawiCiooYeU9eQu":{
               "shares":365.07991498000007,
               "invalidshares":0,
               "hashrate":79752.92436043094,
               "hashrateString":"79.75 KH"
            },
            "Gz2Llan6hTkm8qLhSHh34awiCiooYe17heT":{
               "shares":365.07991498000007,
               "invalidshares":0,
               "hashrate":79752.92436043094,
               "hashrateString":"79.75 KH"
            }
         },
         "hashrate":79752.92436043094,
         "workerCount":1,
         "hashrateString":"79.75 KH"
      }
   }
}
```

I'm having trouble deserializing these two parts specifically:

```
"algos":{
  "scrypt-n":{
     "workers":1,
     "hashrate":79752.92436043094,
     "hashrateString":"79.75 KH"
  }
```

},

```
"workers":{
        "Gf3ZXqhWKkm8qLhSHvyrawiCiooYeU9eQu":{
           "shares":365.07991498000007,
           "invalidshares":0,
           "hashrate":79752.92436043094,
           "hashrateString":"79.75 KH"
        },
        "Gz2Llan6hTkm8qLhSHh34awiCiooYe17heT":{
           "shares":365.07991498000007,
           "invalidshares":0,
           "hashrate":79752.92436043094,
           "hashrateString":"79.75 KH"
        }
     },
```

**The Code I've Tried**

```
namespace pooldecode
```

{

```
public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this jsonDecode.Root self)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
    }
}

public class Converter
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
    };
}
public class jsonDecode
{

    public static Root FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json/*, Converter.Settings*/);


    public partial class Root
    {
        [J("time")] public long Time { get; set; }
        [J("global")] public Global Global { get; set; }
        [J("algos")] public List<Algos> Algos { get; set; }
        [J("pools")] public List<Pools> Pools { get; set; }

    }

    public partial class Algos
    {
        [J("workers")] public int Workers { get; set; }
        [J("hashrate")] public double Hashrate { get; set; }
        [J("hashrateString")] public string HashrateString { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Global
    {
        [J("workers")] public int Workers { get; set; }
        [J("hashrate")] public long Hashrate { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Pools
    {
        [J("crypto")] public List<Crypto> Crypto { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Crypto
    {
        [J("name")] public string Name { get; set; }
        [J("symbol")] public string Symbol { get; set; }
        [J("algorithm")] public string Algorithm { get; set; }
        [J("poolStats")] public PoolStats PoolStats { get; set; }
        [J("blocks")] public Blocks Blocks { get; set; }
        [J("workers")] public Workers Workers { get; set; }
        [J("hashrate")] public double Hashrate { get; set; }
        [J("workerCount")] public long WorkerCount { get; set; }
        [J("hashrateString")] public string HashrateString { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Blocks
    {
        [J("pending")] public long Pending { get; set; }
        [J("confirmed")] public long Confirmed { get; set; }
        [J("orphaned")] public long Orphaned { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class PoolStats
    {
        [J("validShares")] public string ValidShares { get; set; }
        [J("validBlocks")] public string ValidBlocks { get; set; }
        [J("invalidShares")] public string InvalidShares { get; set; }
        [J("invalidRate")] public string InvalidRate { get; set; }
        [J("totalPaid")] public string TotalPaid { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Workers
    {
        [J("worker")] public List<Workers> Worker { get; set;  }
        [J("shares")] public double Shares { get; set; }
        [J("invalidshares")] public long Invalidshares { get; set; }
        [J("hashrate")] public double Hashrate { get; set; }
        [J("hashrateString")] public string HashrateString { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class Worker
    {
        [J("shares")] public double Shares { get; set; }
        [J("invalidshares")] public long Invalidshares { get; set; }
        [J("hashrate")] public double Hashrate { get; set; }
        [J("hashrateString")] public string HashrateString { get; set; }
    }





}
```

}

Comment: Please post the code in C# that you have tried that is not working.

Comment: @codeMonkey added

Comment: Use Json.NET. Dont inline your attributes like that, its really unreadable.  What exactly is the problem with your serializing/deserializing?  There are no arrays here, its just an object structure.  What specific issues are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Algos`, `Pools` and `Workers` have named properties as childrens, you can't deserialize them as `List<T>` since they are `Dictionary<string, T>`,

Use these classes to deserialize:

```
public partial class Root
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("time")] public long Time { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("global")] public Global Global { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("algos")] public Dictionary<string, Algo> Algos { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("pools")] public Dictionary<string, Pool> Pools { get; set; }
}

public partial class Global
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("workers")] public int Workers { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("hashrate")] public long Hashrate { get; set; }
}

public partial class Algo
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("workers")] public int Workers { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("hashrate")] public double Hashrate { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("hashrateString")] public string HashrateString { get; set; }
}

public partial class Pool
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("name")] public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("symbol")] public string Symbol { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("algorithm")] public string Algorithm { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("poolStats")] public PoolStats PoolStats { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("blocks")] public Blocks Blocks { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("workers")] public Dictionary<string, Worker> Workers { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("hashrate")] public double Hashrate { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("workerCount")] public long WorkerCount { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("hashrateString")] public string HashrateString { get; set; }
}

public partial class Blocks
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("pending")] public long Pending { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("confirmed")] public long Confirmed { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("orphaned")] public long Orphaned { get; set; }
}

public partial class PoolStats
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("validShares")] public string ValidShares { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("validBlocks")] public string ValidBlocks { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("invalidShares")] public string InvalidShares { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("invalidRate")] public string InvalidRate { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("totalPaid")] public string TotalPaid { get; set; }
}
public partial class Worker
{
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("shares")] public double Shares { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("invalidshares")] public long Invalidshares { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("hashrate")] public double Hashrate { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyAttribute("hashrateString")] public string HashrateString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @maccettura It is just a simple find/replace of OP's code, I didn't bother further formatting it.